# log4j not logging into file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO
log4j.logger.com.app.yum.package.WatchDog=INFO,logfile

log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.file=watchdog/watchdog.log
log4j.appender.logfile.maxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.logfile.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.logfile.append=true
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d | %-5p | %m | %c | %t%n
```

I am using above config in log4j properties file. I could see a new file has been created but there are no logs inside it.
Instead I see the logs on console. What I am trying to do is log all the logs of particular class in a file `watchdog.log`.

Below is my logger initialization

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WatchDog.class);
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I suspect there is really no log messages at or above INFO level?

Comment: Its there I could see it on console

Comment: Your logging config doesn't specify a console appender anywhere, so if you're seeing messages logged on the console then I suspect it's not using the config file you think it's using.

Comment: @IanRoberts I have also thought of Log4J is loading another config.  However, OP mentioned that the log file got created but just nothing is logged inside, which seems suggest to me the config file is really used.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell the `log4j` to log on file,

**First add:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
```

Then you need to specify the file `Appender` like:

```
#settings for FILE: output to file using standard TTCC pattern
#this option backs up the file daily with a date stamp
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd

#this option backs up the file after is reaches a specified size
#log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1KB
#log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3

#optionally change the filepath to the log file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=D:/Reliances/reliance90e_NOVO/logs/reliance.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ContextPrinting=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.DateFormat=ISO8601
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=DEBUG
```

and to intialzed the logger you can do:

```
//From org.apache.log4j.Logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(obj.getClass().getName());
```

**Note:** The value are an example and the also i want to show you the different options in the File Appender, also this configurations should be added to your another configurations.

Comment: where do i specify my class name? I just want to do logging for specific class

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.  You don't need to always have the root logger send to file appender.

Comment: @rrs120486 if i got your question, the see my updated answer.